# What does "Q" stand for in the context of graphing?

Tags: terminologie

In the phrase "Courbes trop pointues, réduire l'échelle des Q", what does Q mean/stand for?

Comment: Pics or +it didn't happen+ we can't see what you mean.

Comment: Pictures of what? I've written the entire phrase in the question.

Comment: @outis: une image de la courbe, what else ?

Comment: He's talking about pointy curves in general, not any specific ones.

Comment: I guess some variable is named *Q*, right? In this context *échelle* means “scale”.

Comment: Sans contexte, cette question ne veut rien dire. C'est une notation scientifique qui doit être précisée quelque part ou qui est standard dans un domaine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le facteur Q n'est pas lié à la langue française puisqu'il existe dans toute les langues.

[Facteur Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor)

Comment: Huhu, intéressant. Le *facteur de qualité* d'un oscillateur, donc ? La limite que je vois à cette explication, c'est que ce facteur n'est pas sur le graphe, a priori (ou alors, assez indirectement), donc *réduire son échelle* ne veut pas dire grand-chose. Mais si c'est bien de ça dont il s'agit, bien vu.

Comment: Sans plus d'informations, difficile de tirer plus de conclusions

Comment: Note: This isn't a graphing term, it is a physics and engineering term.

Answer (score 3):

En supposant que Q est bien une variable (*Quantité* ?), ce à quoi ça me fait penser ne vaut pas mille mots¹ :

[image: Imgur]

Par contre, évidemment, Q n'a alors aucun sens en français, c'est simplement un moyen de désigner l'axe des abscisses.

---

Eh, on est d'humeur artiste où on ne l'est pas, et heureusement que l'humeur ne requiert aucun talent.

¹ Ni traduction.